# Separate home controller for subsite in silverstripe 3

Tags: silverstripe

I have successfully installed subsite module in silverstripe, I just wanted to know that, is it possible to create 2 separate HomePage controller for main site and subsite.
I am trying to remove gallery field and tab from subsite home page not from main site home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are both homepages the same controller by default or two totally different controllers? You can check in your `getCMSFields()` for the current subsite ID

```
if ($this->SubsiteID !== 1) {
    //remove fields
    $fields->remove('NameOfTab'); //e.g. 'Gallery' for tab Root.Gallery
    //do other stuff
}
```

In frontend or when you're not in a Dataobject or Page which is directly related to a subsite you can check for the subsite calling `Subsite::currentSubsiteID()`, see [code on github](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites/blob/master/code/model/Subsite.php#L103)